# Centering footer webpage

Tags: html, css

I'm building an website, and i've a wrap class to fix some elements to the center of the webpage. But with the footer menu this is not happening, in the other hand I can do it with logo and some text. I've this code: [here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WTE2v/)

```
<div id="footer">
    <div id="footer_menu" class="wrap">
        <div id="fst_column" class="divider footer_column">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li>SomeText</li>
                <li>SomeText</li>
                <li>SomeText</li>
                <li>SomeText</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="sec_column" class="divider menu footer_column">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li>SomeText</li>
                <li>SomeText</li>
                <li>SomeText</li>
                <li>SomeText</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="trd_column" class="divider menu footer_column">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li>SomeText</li>
                <li>SomeText</li>
                <li>SomeText</li>
                <li>SomeText</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="frth_column" class="divider menu footer_column">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li>SomeText</li>
                <li>SomeText</li>
                <li>SomeText</li>
                <li>SomeText</li>
                <li>SomeText</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="fvth_column" class="divider menu footer_column">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li>SomeText</li>
                <li>SomeText</li>
                <li>SomeText</li>
                <li>SomeText</li>
                <li>SomeText</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <img id="logo_small" src="images/logo_small.png"/>
    <div id="copyright" class="wrap">
        Some Copyright text
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap{
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear:both;
}

ul.menu{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.divider{
    height:90px;
    border-left:2px solid white;
}

#footer{
    width: 100%;
    height:100px;
    left:0px;
}

#footer_menu {
    overflow: hidden;
    float:left;
    width:85%;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( 45deg, rgb(0,159,194), rgb(0,15,61)); /* Safari */
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( 45deg, rgb(0,159,194), rgb(0,15,61)); /* Firefox */
}

.footer_column{
    width: 175px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-top:10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 15px;
    font-family: "Quicksand";
    float:left;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}

#frth_column, #fvth_column{
    color:rgb(142,216,248);
}
```

The copyright text behaves correctly (also the logo in the top of the webpage) but the footer part dont.

I guess I'm doing something wrong with the float part. How can I put the footer part also in the center of the webpage.

The five columns are supposed to be inline and with a logo out of the blue area.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Added layout printscreen[image: Layout example]

Edit2: How i want the menu [image: Desired menu]

Comment: The image src is `images/logo_small.png`, this refers to a local image to your website, we can't see it so basically we don't know how it would look like. You should put the entire http link there so we can exactly see what the image looks like.

Comment: the problem is not on the image, is on the footer columns. In my preview they are all to the left I want them centered.

Answer (score 0):

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/guinatal/WTE2v/8/

HTML

```
<div id="footer">
    <div id="footer_menu" class="wrap">
        <center>
        <div id="fst_column" class="divider footer_column">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li>SomeText</li>
                <li>SomeText</li>
                <li>SomeText</li>
                <li>SomeText</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="sec_column" class="divider menu footer_column">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li>SomeText</li>
                <li>SomeText</li>
                <li>SomeText</li>
                <li>SomeText</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </center>
    </div>
    <img id="logo_small" src="images/logo_small.png"/>
    <div id="copyright" class="wrap">
        Some Copyright text
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap{
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear:both;
}

ul.menu{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.divider{
    height:90px;
    border-left:2px solid white;
}

#footer{
    width: 100%;
    height:100px;
    left:0px;
}

#footer_menu {
    overflow: hidden;
    float:left;
    width:85%;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( 45deg, rgb(0,159,194), rgb(0,15,61)); /* Safari */
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( 45deg, rgb(0,159,194), rgb(0,15,61)); /* Firefox */
}

.footer_column{
    width: 175px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-top:10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 15px;
    font-family: "Quicksand";
    display:inline-block;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}

#frth_column, #fvth_column{
    color:rgb(142,216,248);
}
```

Comment: as I said, the copyright and top logo are behaving correctly. the problem is on the footer menu. I added a layout example

Comment: Remove "float: left" from #footer_menu

Comment: when i do that all goes a bit to right, including the background. I want the background to stays the same, but columns shifted

Comment: in that case i'll have also the background smaller. I wanna keep the blue area starting in the left, but the "data" only show after, like centered

Comment: also not working... dont know what I'm doing wrong...
Am I doing a multi column footer in the right way? I mean with right div, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Insert `text-align:center;` in id `footer-menu`

```
#footer_menu {
    overflow: hidden;
    float:left;
    width:85%;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( 45deg, rgb(0,159,194), rgb(0,15,61)); /* Safari */
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( 45deg, rgb(0,159,194), rgb(0,15,61)); /* Firefox */
    text-align:center; // Changed
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WTE2v/6/)

Comment: that will align the text inside of each column. all I want is to "shift" all the 5 columns, aligned with the logo.

Comment: You want the columns to be aligned in the middle of the footer?

Comment: yes, i added an image with the location where i want the menu. In resume i want my webpage to be displayed in a 1024 screen and also in larger screens, where the data is all in the center

that's why i created the wrap class